# ¿Cómo cambiar un botton desde un select dinámico?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

tengo un formulario donde uso 2 selects,1 escoge el área ("Administracion","fizacal",etc) y de acorde a ello rellena el otro select, lo que quiero es que al momento de seleccionar el segundo select, me cambie de boton o me cambie la ruta de destino de ese boton
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código:

- Primer  y segundo select:

  ```
  <select id="primary" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">Administración</option>
      <option value="2">Áreas Verdes</option>
      <option value="3">Limpieza Publica</option>
      <option value="4">Calidad Ambiental</option>
      <option value="5">Recursos Humanos</option>
      <option value="6">Logística</option>
  </select>

   <select class="form-control" id="secondary">
   </select>
  ```
- Botón que quiero cambiar:

  <button type="submit" name="btnImprimir"class="btn btn-warning" formtarget="_blank"
  formaction="http://localhost/DocSoliQueja">
  IMPRIMIR Y FIRMAR
- Script para select dinamico

  ```
          var options = {

            1: ["Oficio", "Carta", "Memorando"],

            2: ["Oficio", "Carta", "Solicitud"],

            3: ["Oficio", "Carta", "Solicitud"],

            4: ["Oficio", "Carta"],

            5: ["Oficio", "Carta", "Oficio Múltiple"],

            6: ["Oficio", "Carta", "Solicitud"],          

        }
    $(function() {
        var fillSecondary = function() {
            var selected = $('#primary').val();
            $('#secondary').empty();
            options[selected].forEach(function(element, index) {
                $('#secondary').append('<option value="' + element + '">' + element + '</option>');
            });
        }
        $('#primary').change(fillSecondary);
        fillSecondary();
    });
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega el evento **change** al select **#secondary** y luego en acción del evento cambia el valor del atributo **formaction** con el método **setAttribute**.

```
var changeAction = function() {
    let btnSubmit = document.querySelector('button[name="btnImprimir"]');

    // ejm de formar una nueva url
    let url = btnSubmit.getAttribute('formaction');
    url += ('/' + $(this).val());

    btnSubmit.setAttribute('formaction', url);
}

$('#secondary').change(changeAction);
```